# Can't create new bucket in google cloud storage by gsutil

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to create a new bucket by manually using command on `cmd`. However, I can't create a new bucket. The system reports the following error:

> gsutil mb gs://gms01
>       Creating gs://gms01/...
>       You are attempting to access protected data with no configured credentials.
>       Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project and sign up for an account,
>       and then run the "gsutil config" command to configure gsutil to use these credentials.

Please tell me know to solve this error.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try gsutil ls

Comment: Have you signed up for an account and enabled billing? You can't create buckets without first enabling billing and then configuring gsutil credentials for your account.

Comment: Yes, I singed up and enabled billing. I can create new bucket and upload my data into cloud storage by manually but I can't with gsutil

Comment: Did you run `gsutil config` ?